# Are nuclear operator between Banach spaces compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(E,\|\cdot\|_E), (F,\|\cdot\|_F)$ two Banach spaces. Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset E', (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset F$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n\|_{E'}\|y_n\|_F<+\infty$.

I want to prove that the operator $T:E\longrightarrow F$ define as $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)y_n$ is compact.

This operator, is named the 'nuclear operator' between $E$ and $F$.

My proof is:

- Prove $T$ is bounded. ✓
- Define for all $m\in \mathbb{N} \ T_m:E\longrightarrow F$ as $T_mx=\sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x)y_n$. Prove that $T_m$ is bounded. ✓
- Prove that $T_m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}T$ in $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$. ✓
- Prove that $T_m$ is compact for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we conclude that $T$ is compact. Here I am having some troubles.

I'm trying to prove it with the claim:

$T$ is a compact operator iff $\forall (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded sequence in $E$, the sequence $(Tx_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence in $F$.

I see that if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $E$, as $T_m$ is bounded, $(Tx_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is also bounded in $F$. But I didn't know how to select a subsequence that converge in $F$.

Comment: Here's a hint: For every bounded sequence $x_k$ you hvae that $f_1(x_k)$ is bounded in the base field $\Bbb K$. In the base field bounded sequences admit convergent sub-sequences, so you may pass to a sub-sequence $x_{k_l}$ so that $f_1(x_{k_l})$ converges. can you repeat this $m$ times, once for each $f_n$, $n=1,..., m$ to get that $T_m(x_k)$ admits a convergent subsequence? Alternatively: Show that $T_m$ is a finite rank map.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the first strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The $T_{m}$ that you have defined are finite rank operators, which are compact since they have finite dimensional range. Since you have showed that the the operator $T$ is a norm limit of finite rank operators which are compact, you have that the operator $T$ is compact.